# How can I return all results for mysql query and display in order according Order field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called writing with multiple records having the same SID and I want the below code to return all records where approved = "Y" and display them one after another (append the latest order No. for that SID after the most recent order number.

The database records look like this:

```
SID  Approved   Order  Text
18     Y          1    text block one
18     N          2    text block two, but don't want to display after one b/c not approved
18     Y          2    text block two
```

I want the result to be:

Text block one
Text block two

Here is the code I have so far (without having added the "order" query yet):

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name,
stories.SID, stories.story_name, stories.category,
writing.text, writing.approved
FROM stories
INNER JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID = wp_users.ID
INNER JOIN writing ON stories.SID = writing.SID
WHERE (stories.SID = $the_SID) AND (writing.approved = 'Y')");
```

I'm just not sure how to approach this as this is a new type of query for me. Also, the code as is does not even return all the results for SID=18 and approved=Y currently. It only returns the first result....

Comment: add an `order by` clause?

Comment: My guess is that `ON stories.ID = wp_users.ID` is not what you want, but it's hard to say without seeing your table schemas.

Comment: I need the ON stories.ID = wp_users.ID so I can first connect the tables to get the story for the user. Marc might be correct about using an order by clause. But can either of you see why this is so far returning just one result (the first result) as written so far? Once I figure that out I can try the order by

Comment: You should show your table structures (you can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName;` and paste the output).